# silviomoreto bootstrap-select not loading options, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I just grabbed the example code at http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ to try it out on my page.  I don't know why I can't get the bootstrap-select to work.  There are no options/no dropdown list of options (see image).  What am I missing here? There are a ton of .css and js files  (uses bootstrap 3.x) on the site I'm working on, but I created a template page just so I could try this out.  Would someone help me with this? I've read posts here on SO, but I'm not finding the answer I need.   Thanks.

Here is the order of the .css files in the `<head>`:

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />    
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-overrides.css" />
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lib/bootstrap-select.css" />
>   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" />
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lib/font-awesome.css" />    
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom-add/layout.css" />
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom-add/elements.css" />
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom-add/icons.css" />
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" /> 
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kendo/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css"/>   
>   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kendo/kendo.bootstrap.min.css"/>   
>   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/fav.png" />
>
> <!--[if lt IE 9]>
>   <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
> <![endif]-->
> ```

```
<body>
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Choose a topping.">
                        <option>Mustard</option>
                        <option>Ketchup</option>
                        <option>Relish</option>
                    </select>
```

Here is the scripts order:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>       
  <script src="bower_components/store.js/store.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/data.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
  <script src="js/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/kendo/kendo.angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>   
  <script src="js/theme.js"></script>

    <!--jquery: -->
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
     });
```

[image: select no options]

Comment: Are you seeing errors in the browser console? How about starting with a minimal example like this? http://www.bootply.com/0wnCvjkaWV

Comment: @Skelly thanks.  I've done the tutorials listed on the bootstrap site which contains minimal code and of course they all work fine.  I want to know if maybe the problem I am having lies in the order of the files.  As I said, there are alot of files on this site, and though I didn't write the code, I would like to add the bootstrap-select feature to the site.